# logical OR combine 2 or more observable streams

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I have 2 observables that both indicate if they're loading data or not. They come from @ngrx/data.

```
loadingA$: Observable<boolean>
loadingB$: Observable<boolean>
```

I'd like to "logical OR" combine the two to do whatever when either is true, using rxjs or more elegant method. Maybe ramdajs?, maybe a combined loading state? However different components need different combinations of loading streams.

Also, what if I have 20 streams, it shouldn't be limited to 2 streams only.

(!) I do not want to assign additional local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combineLatest(loadingA$, loadingB$).pipe(map((a, b) => a || b));
```

or

```
const anyLoading = (...observables: Observable<boolean>[]) => combineLatest(observables).pipe(
  map(bools => bools.some(loading => loading))
);
```

and use it

```
anyLoading(loadingA$, loadingB$);
```

```js
const { combineLatest, BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;
const { map } = rxjs.operators;

const anyLoading = (...observables) => combineLatest(observables).pipe(
  map(bools => bools.some(loading => loading))
);

const loadingA$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
const loadingB$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);

anyLoading(loadingA$, loadingB$).subscribe(loading => { console.log(loading); });

loadingB$.next(false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Property 'some' does not exist on type 'Observable<boolean[]>'.` It's not a typo. I copied the 2nd line exactly as you wrote it.

Comment: Sorry I missed a map in the pipe. Updated with working demo.

Comment: :D all good, thanks for the answer. It logs the values false, true, true, false (end). The component however doesn't show or hide with *ngIf, but that's out of scope of the question. Turns out it didn't take long enough to load to actually display the loading element. So yeah, thanks again.